# matcher library for .net

Tags: .net, hamcrest, matcher

Does any matcher libraries exist for .net?
I am talking about a library like the hamcrest library for java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I have yet found is the matchers in Moq:
http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart

http://weblogs.manas.com.ar/bcardiff/2009/02/reimproved-argument-matchers-in-moq/

However this is very tightly coupled to the mocking framework, I would like something more seperate.

Comment: I have found that the mocking framework is excactly where I need matchers.

Answer (score 5):

Graham Hay has a .NET port of Hamcrest on GitHub:

https://github.com/grahamrhay/NHamcrest